# How to call a thread inside another function and defined in main?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am doing a code on c++ .Now I am confused with thread function or basic c++concepts . I have a header file ,function file and a main function file .

header.h

```
class Employee : public Library
{

private:

pthread_t my_thread;//thread declare

public:

Employee();
int issueBook();

};
```

main.cpp

```
class threadClass
{
public:

void *worker_thread(void *arg)
{
    char *curtime;

    char *bk_time = (char *)arg;

    time_t now = time(0);

    curtime = ctime(&now);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
  }
 };

int main()
{
  Employee emp ;
  emp.issueBook(); //calling function
}
```

and function.cpp

```
int Employee :: issueBook()
{
   int ret =0;

   ret =  pthread_create(&my_thread, NULL, &worker_thread,(void *)temp->book_time);//thread calling with a function name and argument
}
```

How can I call a thread function defined in  `main.cpp` file from `function.cpp` file ? Can I call using object of class `threadClass` ? Can I get this `threadClass` object in `function.cpp` file ?

Comment: Why do you put the so-called "thread function" in main.cpp?

Comment: i want to use thread function in main function

Comment: A header file that declares the thread function prototype, then included by both `main.cpp` and `function.cpp`  would seem reasonable.

Comment: That would be the part about "basic c++concepts" you mentioned earlier. Including header files is discussed in every C++ tutorial and text ever written, no matter how remedial. I suggest you start with, quite literally, *any* of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong with your code is that pthread_create needs a function pointer as thread entry point, while you supply &worker_thread, which is not a function but a member function of threadClass.

You have two options:

1. Get rid of threadClass turning worker_thread into a function
2. declare worker_thread statis, and pass &threadClass::worker_thread to pthread_create